# Resizing only the height of CardView also changes the width

Tags: android, animation, cardview

I currently have a recycler view that has a list of CardViews. 
When I click on the card I want to be able to expand the card (change only the height). This is working fine by setting the new height to the card with an animation.

The problem is that when I click to expand the card, the width also shrinks to less than half the width of the screen. If I scroll the view away and come back the width is set correctly. Every time I try to expand the height, it expands to the right size but the width shrinks.

Is there something that I'm supposed to do to expand/collapse a card in a recycler view and not have this side effect of also resizing the card width?

I tried only setting the height in a valueAnimator and that works for the expansion. 
I tried to set the width programmatically at the end of the animation to match parent but that has no effect.

Comment: It may be helpful if you share some relevant code. Can you share what you have implemented surrounding the CardView including your java/kotlin, xml (including styles if any), and animation?

Answer (score 0):

for better solution pls share code with us, until that.

check your xml codes for any Wrap content value for width.

It will solve your issue.